# Convert Video to text(transcript) by google cloud speech to text with Rails Application

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails-5, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Working on a WebAppon Ruby on Rails.
I want to get subtitle for Pre recorded video and also for new videos going to record.

I have implemented the `gem 'google-cloud-speech'`.

But now I'm not able to get text for my video. I get a suggestion from Google Cloud API doc to add model but when I add  `model: 'video'` to configuration, it says there is no such field `model` in initialization map entry.

My code without adding model is as per below.

```
speech_client = Google::Cloud::Speech.new
config ={ encoding: :LINEAR16,
          sample_rate_hertz: 16000,
          language_code: "en-US",
        }
audio = { uri: @uri }
response = speech.recognize config, audio
```

which is giving me error message like below.

`` Google::Gax::RetryError: GaxError Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by 3:Request contains an invalid argument.
from /Users/hiren/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@Snip/gems/google-gax-1.3.0/lib/google/gax/api_callable.rb:369:in `rescue in block in retryable' ``

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the model issue, this might be due to that the [video model](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/video-model) is not available yet for Ruby `V1` API version as this feature it's part of the `v1p1beta1` version.

Regarding your code issue, I just did the example shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize#performing_synchronous_speech_recognition_on_a_remote_file) successfully. It would be helpful if you attach your full code as the documented code works well.

Comment: It seems like the media file should be on google cloud?

Comment: Yes, currently only Cloud Storage [URIs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionAudio) are supported

Comment: Is it possible to achieve it anyhow like calling APIs directly without using Gem.

Comment: If you don't want to install the client libraries, you could make an [HTTP POST request](https://coderwall.com/p/c-mu-a/http-posts-in-ruby). For instance, you could use the JSON body shown in [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol#make_an_audio_transcription_request) document. However, you'll need to do the authentication to use the API.